# nginx rewrite middle of url to another pattern

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

This nginx rule works great for me for a full specified file path

rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /sitemap.php last;

When I acces sitemap.xml it works as expected but in the background sitemap.php is requested. So far so goode.

Another problem arised and I need to rewrite the last part of existing urls

```
rewrite ^doctor-solution.html/ doctor-answer.html/ permanent;
```

What I want to achive is when an old url like
`https://example.com/case12232-doctor-solution.html/` is accessed
it must be redirected to

```
https://example.com/case12232-doctor-answer.html/
```

But My rule doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Did't you know the `^` sign means the beginning of the string? Are you URL really ends with `.html/` (including the trailing slash)? If so, you can try `rewrite ^(.*)-doctor-solution.html/$ $1-doctor-answer.html/ permanent;`

Comment: @IvanShatsky Are you available for hire? Contact me albfactor at gmail.com for this job

Comment: @IvanShatsky When you read this message contact me, I'd like to buy you a coffe